# tidyr Based reshape code not yielding result in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na, tidyr

I have the following dataframe

```
df1<-data.frame( "ID"=c("ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID2", "ID1"),"A_Frequency"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "A_Axis"=c(.2,.3,.2,.4,.2),"B_Frequency"=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), "B_Axis"=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

The dataframe looks as follows

```
   ID   A_Frequency A_Axis  B_Frequency B_Axis
1 ID1           1    0.2          NA     NA
2 ID1           2    0.3          NA     NA
3 ID2           3    0.2          NA     NA
4 ID2           4    0.4          NA     NA
5 ID1           5    0.2          NA     NA
```

I wish to reshape the frame as follows(expected output)

```
  ID  A_Frequency  A_Axis   B_Frequency B_Axis
1 ID1         1     0.2           1     NA
2 ID1         2     0.3           2     NA
3 ID1         3     NA            3     NA
4 ID1         4     NA            4     NA
5 ID1         5     0.2           5     NA
6 ID2         3     0.2           3     NA
7 ID2         4     0.4           4     NA
```

I have tried the following code to obtain the above output

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% complete(ID, nesting(A_Frequency=full_seq(A_Frequency,1), 
B_Frequency=full_seq(B_Frequency,1)))
```

I am getting the following error.

```
 Error in UseMethod("full_seq") : 
 no applicable method for 'full_seq' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

Can I get some help to accomplish the same.

Comment: Here what I would do. `df1 %>% complete(ID, nesting(A_Frequency=full_seq(A_Frequency,1))) %>% mutate(B_Frequency=A_Frequency) %>% filter(ID=='ID1' | (ID=='ID2' & !is.na(A_Axis)))`

Comment: Thank you. Can it be extended to multiple columns also. Like C_Frequency, C_Axis. IN the sense that we use na.omit(unique(c(B_Frequency, A_Frequency))) in the place of mutate.

Comment: How you will do `na.omit(unique(c(B_Frequency, A_Frequency)))`. Yes, it can be extended if it's in the same structure.

Comment: Like it is basically that A_frequency , B_Frequency, C_Frequency should have a similar structure and minimum and maximum across all three columns should be identical